# What's the best way to choose the concurrency level for a ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, hashmap

I was trying to understand how the concurrency level of ConcurrentHashMap works (third argument to its constructor) and was reading this article -- https://dzone.com/articles/how-concurrenthashmap-works-internally-in-java .  Specifically, it defines the concurrency level as

> Defines the number which is an estimated number of concurrently
>   updating threads. The implementation performs internal sizing to try
>   to accommodate this     many threads.

It then defines how a segment is selected using

```
Segment seg = segments[(hash & 0x1F)];
```

where "hash" is the hash code of the object being inserted.  My question is, since you may not always be able to predict the hash value of inserted objects, is it possible that if you have a concurrency level of 16, could you theoretically get in a situation where all objects get inserted into the same segment?  If so, does it make sense to always choose the number of segments based on how many threads may access the data structure or is there a better way to select the concurrency level?

Comment: The best thing to do is not to worry about it unless you have a performance problem that you've actually profiled to this issue.

Comment: JDK 8 and up do not use Segments any more, except for serialization purposes (I believe, so that the serialized objects are backwards compatible). In any case, the javadoc for `ConcurrentHashMap` points out: "Note that using many keys with exactly the same {@code hashCode()} is a sure way to slow down performance of any hash table." hashCodes are _supposed_ to have a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 0):

When you use your own objects as map keys, you have full control of the implementation of `hashCode`. For example you could define it to be the constant value of 0 for all instances of your keys. This is a valid (and very unfortunate) hashing function. With this in mind yes, there can be situations where all objects get inserted into the same segment and even into the same bin.

In general though, the specific hash values are not important but their statistical properties are.

Comment: When you say the specific hash values aren't important but the "statistical properties are," what are statistical properties?  Are you referring to the concurrency bucket number specified in the ConcurrencyHashMap argument?

Comment: I am referring to the probability of bin collisions given the set of the keys (and their associated hash values) you are actually using and the way the map implementation bins those values. Ideally the key hash values should be "evenly" distributed but the Map implementation may do some extra work to even them out - see `ConcurrentHashMap.spread()` for example.